# Is it possible to lock an adapter's data during layout or draw passes?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a view adapter that accesses a collection. I would like to lock the collection for the duration of any layout phases, or phases when getView might be called. I do not want to lock per access.

My question is, are there view callbacks available on the view or the adapter that I can hook into to lock my data collection?

Comment: What should happen while the Adapter is locked and value in the adapter should be changed? Should the change be queued or rejected or...

Comment: IMO the operation should block